# Android App in English only but Slide ME claims it supports all languages

Tags: android, internationalization

I am trying to release my first Android App. It has a great deal of dialogue so I opted for English only. All the dialogue is in the program code and none of it is in strings.xml.

When I uploaded my .apk to Slide ME for certification, the preview screen claimed that my game supported every language from Urdu to Tagalog, etc. I sent them an email and they claim that this information is drawn from my .apk file.

Is this true? Is there some way to indicate (perhaps in my Android Manifest) that the game is solely in English?

Comment: What folders do you have under `res/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the google-play-services api (for ads perhaps?) it will have the effect of announcing support for 57 languages.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. My app does use Google Play services with AdMob (which created numerous other problems during setup I might add). Is there any way to change this behavior of announcing support for 57 languages (to avoid users thinking my game will run in Malay and then giving me a one-star review when it fails to do so, etc.)